# Giving me error - Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

Shifted to mac, and trying to run an important but old flutter project.

**Tried changing java version from 1.8 to 11 to 17, nothing works. Tried changing gradle version in gradle.wrapper properties.**
Please help.

**My gradle.wrapper properties-**

```
#Thu May 18 17:14:41 IST 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

**My build.gradle in android/build.gradle (also tried changing the build.gradle classpath)-**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**I don't know why my - /mylibrary/build.gradle is showing error**

[image]

**Error log -**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.2-all.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.2-all.zip
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have downgraded my flutter version to 1.7 as the new flutter and dart were not compatible with null dependencies and I was facing a lot of bugs because of that.

Any idea how I can fix that.

Comment: If i change my gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` , the error in the mylibrary/build.gradle vanishes but the compilation error remains. No idea if I should upgrade the build-wrapper. properties  to 7.4.2 or not. I have tried lots of permutations, nothing works :(